# how can i change my date range picker first time showing month

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I am using date range picker for filter option. In default date picker shows the current month and next month. but I need  previous month and current month. How can I do this?

```js
 $('#Date').daterangepicker();
```

```html
<!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />
 
<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />

 <div id="Date" class="col-xs-5 col-md-4 paddingNull filterImageAlign" >here select</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to your js code:

```
$('#Date').daterangepicker({
     "startDate": "-1m",
     "endDate": '+1m'
)};
```

Comment: thanks .. its working. and one more, how can i hide the date after today's date

Comment: means i want to hide the date or in active that days